# Best setup for Ubuntu running on USB3 thumb drive

Tags: usb, live-usb, usb-drive

First of all, my apologies for my complete lack of ignorance of all things Linux. The last time I had a linux box I used with any regularity, President Clinton was still in office.

I am running Ubuntu from a 2 partitions 64GB USB3 thumbdrive (one for Ubuntu one for files).

I don't have a huge SSD drive (yet), and I need as much of the space on it as I can for my Windows 10 installation. Also, I would like to run the same instance of Ubuntu on my Laptop, desktop and my wife's laptop as needed, without having to reconfigure Ubuntu each time or have 3 separate installations.

I have done some tests already and I have read many relevant posts on this and other forums, however, I have encountered some issues:

Upon Installation (after running Ubuntu in "Demo" mode off the USB TD) I was unable to install Ubuntu on either another thumbdrive or a external  320GB drive (of the old fashioned spinning kind) because Ubuntu kept giving me cryptic failure errors before I even got to the partitioning stage. 
I did not want to install Ubuntu in a partition of my laptop's SSD for various reasons, mainly because I need the space for my Win10 OS and it's already at a premium.

When I tried to simply customize the USB drive installation, which is set up as "persistent" I also got some errors when trying to install languages and other programs (the latter did eventually install after a few failures, but not the languages), and then I run out of space and I had no idea how to increase the space. 
As an example, if I were in windows and I had a partitioned drive, I would simply save space on the Boot partition by installing new apps in the other partition. In Linux I have no idea on how to do that.

My ultimate goal is to have an external drive I can take with me and use on any 64bit computer in the home or outside (eventually, I'd create a 32bit version as well for old netbooks) and where I have installed a suite of apps and preferences similar to what one would find in Ubuntu Studio (which I also tested, but it was error city from the beginning, so I figured I can install the apps I need myself).

I have used several tools to create bootable USB thumbdrives. From YUMI (which I have used for a repair disk along with a few distros just for fun and practice) to other tools designed to work with a single distro.

In this new USB3 Thumbdrive I need enough room to install apps like Inkscape, Gimp, Music composition, video editing, code development and so forth without getting out of space error, plus a partition where I can save some files I may want to share, via thumbdrive, with my windows and Mac OS machines. The rest I can simply upload to my various cloud accounts, but the installation has to be able to work even without WiFi available, hence, I need some actual storage space for files as well.

I am not asking for step by step, detailed instructions, but more like pointers to other posts I might have missed, blog posts, "How to's" etc.

No Linux Distro I have tried so far has worked well enough just running off the USB thumbdrive. Regardless of how much persistent space I gave it.

Am I asking too much of Linux? Should I just buy another SSD and swap or find some other way to connect it? Would 2 USB thumbdrives work better? One for the OS another for Files? They are small enough these days.

Thank you.

Comment: You wrote "best" in the title. The best way to make a persistent portable bootable Ubuntu device is to start with a portable USB 3.0 SSD. It has the same form factor as a thumb drive and comes in different sizes up to 256GB. Then follow the instructions in this question: [How do I install Ubuntu to a USB key? (without using Startup Disk Creator)](http://askubuntu.com/questions/16988/how-do-i-install-ubuntu-to-a-usb-key-without-using-startup-disk-creator). However for the same money you could get a bigger internal SSD.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. I ended up using something similar to the article you linked to. In fact, now I have a 64GB Thumb Drive that I partitioned in 2 with one half using YUMI and the other a partition I can use to save my linux files as an external drive. Windows only sees the first partition, of course, but I am using Google Drive and Dropbox to share any files I need on Windows.

Comment: Then I have another USB where I proceeded exactly as illustrated in the post. In fact, I have one for Ubuntu and one for Ubuntu studio so I can have some good graphic, video and programming tools in a stand alone boot I can use on anyone's computer depending on needs. Ubuntu Studio is nice, but not as stable as Ubuntu. I might built my own "studio" version someday.

Comment: One thing I didn't know was that there are SSDs with the same form factor as USB thumbdrives. I have never seen one, or I didn't recognized it as such. I happen to have a 256GB SSD (orphaned when I upgraded to a 500GB a couple of years ago) that I keep in a case and that I have used as both SATA3 and USB3 external drive, but it's not really handy to carry around on my keyring.  I shall research that. What are the differences? and if they both go through USB3 ports is the SSD still faster?  My Samsung USB3 Thumbdrive with YUMI is actually quite fast.

Comment: The motivation for using SSD vs. regular flash drive is not speed but durability. USB flash drives wear out very quickly under the conditions of frequent read/writes associated with a complete installation of Ubuntu on the flash drive.